# Modify specific field text inside double quotations

Tags: text-processing

I to modify everything inside of specific double quotation marks. Example of my work is:

```
<VALUE MAP_ID="1001" MAP="0" MAPNAME="BichonTown" SERVER="0" CHNSERVER="0" NEEDLEVEL="7" TIME="0" WEATHER="0" VEHICLE="1" PVP="0" MINE="0" CONTROL="" ENTERLV="0" ENTERQUEST="0" ENTERITEM="0" NORECONNECT="DQ_910" MINIMAP="1001" VER="200" APPLY_ROW="0" MAP_EXP_RATIO="0" MAP_DROP_RATIO="0" MAP_MONEY_RATIO="0" ORDERLIST="0" /><VALUE MAP_ID="1002" MAP="0_000" MAPNAME="TownHall" SERVER="1" CHNSERVER="1" NEEDLEVEL="0" TIME="1" WEATHER="0" VEHICLE="0" PVP="1" MINE="0" CONTROL="" ENTERLV="0" ENTERQUEST="0" ENTERITEM="0" NORECONNECT="5515" MINIMAP="0" VER="200" APPLY_ROW="0" MAP_EXP_RATIO="0" MAP_DROP_RATIO="0" MAP_MONEY_RATIO="0" ORDERLIST="0" /><VALUE MAP_ID="1003" MAP="0_001" MAPNAME="TownHall" SERVER="1" CHNSERVER="1" NEEDLEVEL="0" TIME="1" WEATHER="0" VEHICLE="0" PVP="1" MINE="0" CONTROL="" ENTERLV="0" ENTERQUEST="0" ENTERITEM="0" NORECONNECT="0" MINIMAP="0" VER="200" APPLY_ROW="0" MAP_EXP_RATIO="0" MAP_DROP_RATIO="0" MAP_MONEY_RATIO="0" ORDERLIST="0" /><VALUE MAP_ID="1004" MAP="0_002" MAPNAME="TownHall" SERVER="1" CHNSERVER="1" NEEDLEVEL="0" TIME="1" WEATHER="0" VEHICLE="0" PVP="1" MINE="0" CONTROL="" ENTERLV="0" ENTERQUEST="0" ENTERITEM="0" NORECONNECT="221" MINIMAP="0" VER="200" APPLY_ROW="0" MAP_EXP_RATIO="0" MAP_DROP_RATIO="0" MAP_MONEY_RATIO="0" ORDERLIST="0" /><VALUE MAP_ID="1005" MAP="1" MAPNAME="LostParadise" SERVER="1" CHNSERVER="1" NEEDLEVEL="7" TIME="0" WEATHER="0" VEHICLE="1" PVP="0" MINE="0" CONTROL="" ENTERLV="0" ENTERQUEST="0" ENTERITEM="0" NORECONNECT="11" MINIMAP="1002" VER="200" APPLY_ROW="0" MAP_EXP_RATIO="0" MAP_DROP_RATIO="0" MAP_MONEY_RATIO="0" ORDERLIST="0" />
```

Everything inside the `NORECONNECT=""` should be set to `0` there are no spaces only letters, numbers or underscores. The result should look like

```
<VALUE MAP_ID="1001" MAP="0" MAPNAME="BichonTown" SERVER="0" CHNSERVER="0" NEEDLEVEL="7" TIME="0" WEATHER="0" VEHICLE="1" PVP="0" MINE="0" CONTROL="" ENTERLV="0" ENTERQUEST="0" ENTERITEM="0" NORECONNECT="0" MINIMAP="1001" VER="200" APPLY_ROW="0" MAP_EXP_RATIO="0" MAP_DROP_RATIO="0" MAP_MONEY_RATIO="0" ORDERLIST="0" /><VALUE MAP_ID="1002" MAP="0_000" MAPNAME="TownHall" SERVER="1" CHNSERVER="1" NEEDLEVEL="0" TIME="1" WEATHER="0" VEHICLE="0" PVP="1" MINE="0" CONTROL="" ENTERLV="0" ENTERQUEST="0" ENTERITEM="0" NORECONNECT="0" MINIMAP="0" VER="200" APPLY_ROW="0" MAP_EXP_RATIO="0" MAP_DROP_RATIO="0" MAP_MONEY_RATIO="0" ORDERLIST="0" /><VALUE MAP_ID="1003" MAP="0_001" MAPNAME="TownHall" SERVER="1" CHNSERVER="1" NEEDLEVEL="0" TIME="1" WEATHER="0" VEHICLE="0" PVP="1" MINE="0" CONTROL="" ENTERLV="0" ENTERQUEST="0" ENTERITEM="0" NORECONNECT="0" MINIMAP="0" VER="200" APPLY_ROW="0" MAP_EXP_RATIO="0" MAP_DROP_RATIO="0" MAP_MONEY_RATIO="0" ORDERLIST="0" /><VALUE MAP_ID="1004" MAP="0_002" MAPNAME="TownHall" SERVER="1" CHNSERVER="1" NEEDLEVEL="0" TIME="1" WEATHER="0" VEHICLE="0" PVP="1" MINE="0" CONTROL="" ENTERLV="0" ENTERQUEST="0" ENTERITEM="0" NORECONNECT="0" MINIMAP="0" VER="200" APPLY_ROW="0" MAP_EXP_RATIO="0" MAP_DROP_RATIO="0" MAP_MONEY_RATIO="0" ORDERLIST="0" /><VALUE MAP_ID="1005" MAP="1" MAPNAME="LostParadise" SERVER="1" CHNSERVER="1" NEEDLEVEL="7" TIME="0" WEATHER="0" VEHICLE="1" PVP="0" MINE="0" CONTROL="" ENTERLV="0" ENTERQUEST="0" ENTERITEM="0" NORECONNECT="0" MINIMAP="1002" VER="200" APPLY_ROW="0" MAP_EXP_RATIO="0" MAP_DROP_RATIO="0" MAP_MONEY_RATIO="0" ORDERLIST="0" />
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the assumption that there's no embedded `"` character inside this field then this can be done with a tool like `sed`

```
sed 's/NORECONNECT="[^"]*"/NORECONNECT="0"/'
```

The first expression means match `NORECONNECT="` followed by zero or more non-`"` characters followed by a `"`"

So this will match things like

```
NORECONNECT="foo"
NORECONENCT="bar"
NORECONNECT=""
```

And then it replace that part with the string

```
NORECONNECT="0"
```

EDIT:

If the word appears more than once on a line then add a `g` to the end:

```
sed 's/NORECONNECT="[^"]*"/NORECONNECT="0"/g'
```

Comment: Thanks the second one done the trick. Everything was in one line.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like XML, so [don't use regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4959010) to edit it, use a real XML parser such as [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xml ed -u '//VALUE/@NORECONNECT' -v 0 file.xml
```

Comment: this is the right answer